# JQUERY- If style = 0 then apply this

Tags: jquery

I want to apply a box-shadow to a div that is coming out from right (onclick) only when the box is visible. If I apply the box shadow with plain css, I can see the shadow when the div is not visible.
In other words:
"box-shadow: 0 10px 20px $black;" to a div, but only if style="right: 0px;"

I'm using sass, but I'm not quite familiar with operators yet.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Do you mean the Js event `onClick` event or are using a `checkbox` or the `:focus` pseudo class?

Comment: Thanks Simplicius for pointing that out. You just made me realise I'm using jQuery to show the div, si I'll use it to add/remove the class